# Setting up multiple ports in WireMock docker set up

Tags: docker, mocking, dockerfile, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Hey guys I'm trying to set up my wiremock docker container to have multiple services running on different ports. Ex. 8083 for service A, 8084 for service B...

however, regardless of how i config, 1 port seems to default to the listening port, would anyone have any tips or fixes for this?

Currently my commands look like:
docker run -d --name $CONTAINER -p 8083:8081 -p 8084:8082 -p 8085:8080

EXPOSE 8083 8084 8085

I'm expecting a different localhost:x/__admins/mappings for each page, is this possible?